# How to stop openlayers from loading on every zoom?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, zoom

I was thinking this sort of stuff was happening in OL by default, but apparently not?

I'm working on an application with a LOT of layers and every time we zoom or pan it starts reloading, which is very annoying as it just adds more and more time to load after the next zoom/pan.

Is there like a way to set some sort of timeout on the zoom/pan events for reloading or am I stuck with a slow application now forever and ever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so in a roundabout way I sort of achieved my goal. I set a timer each time I zoom, then in the ImageLoadFunction of every layer I check if the timer has run out, if it has I let the layer load, otherwise I ignore it.

Really hope that one day this sort of thing gets put into Openlayers itself, but until then this'll do.